# Problems in formatting table and closing tables "boxes" in latex

Tags: latex

I am having problems in adjusting the format for a table in LaTex. The code is the following and the image depicts how the table comes out after compiling:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
  \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    {\textbf{Labels}} & {\textbf{Precision}} & {\textbf{Recall}} & {\textbf{F1-Score}} 

    \\
    % \hline
    \cline{2-9}
    % \textbf{Inactive Modes} & \textbf{Description}\\
    %\hhline{~--}
    {Not Misogynous} & $37.49\%\pm1.91\%$ & $46.13\%$ & $36.15\%\pm2.61\%$ & \\ \hline
    {Not Misogynous} & $37.49\%\pm1.91\%$ & $46.13\%$ & $36.15\%\pm2.61\%$ & \\ \hline

  \end{tabular}
} 
  
  
  \caption{BERTweet binary task}
\label{table:bert_binary}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I don't understand how to add the necessary line to "close" the boxes around the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code.

You specify 4 columns `p{}ccc` while a content of `tabular` body has 5 columns (with the extra ending `&`). This is why the lines are discontinued.

Numbers `X` and `Y` in the argument of `\cline{X-Y}` must not exceed the available number of columns. You define 4 and trying to draw horizontal rule between `2` and `9`. You probably get the error: `Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr`.

You should avoid inserting empty line in tables. Most of the times LaTeX do not accept `\par` in table environments, which is converted from empty lines. It may work in modern packages that use more recent advances in LaTeX.

I also wonder why you enclose cells inside `{...}`. The code works without them. Is there any particular reason? Perhaps in the main code you load `siunitx` and apply `S`-type column. Then, you do have to tell `siunitx` which cells are non-numeric by wrapping cells inside braces. Otherwise, `siunitx` issues error!

Here's my suggestion for the table:

- I defined columns which accept math expressions without extra `$...$`
- The main values and uncertainties are split in columns to improve formatting and spacing
- `booktabs` provides improved rules that arguably improved presentation
- Default gap between the table and its caption seems too large, so I slightly reduced it (requires `caption` package)
- I keep captions of tables at the top and captions of figures at the bottom but this is again a personal preference.

One of the rules I usually follow is to avoid repeated information in tables. The `%` in your case is repeated everywhere. You could remove it and add annotation that values in all three columns are percentages.

Here's the table

[image]

and the code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{position=bottom,skip=3pt}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\(}r<{\)}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\(}r<{\)}}



\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \caption{BERTweet binary task}
  \label{table:bert_binary}
  \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} R@{\;}L c R@{\;}L}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Labels}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Precision}}
    & \textbf{Recall}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{F1-Score}} \\
    \midrule
    Not Misogynous  &   37.49 & \pm1.91   &   46.13   &   36.15 & \pm2.61 \\
    Not Misogynous  &   37.49 & \pm1.91   &   46.13   &   36.15 & \pm2.61 \\
    \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}l@{}}{\footnotesize All values in \%}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answer to this question is very good and detailed, including many observations that is always useful to consider when doing tables in LaTeX. It also addresses you to avoid vertical lines in tables (consistently with the use of the package [`booktabs`](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)).

I add the following code and output just for the sake to remark the minimal edits necessary for your original code to reach a threshold look.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{table}%[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    {\textbf{Labels}} & {\textbf{Precision}} & {\textbf{Recall}} & {\textbf{F1-Score}}\\
    \hline
    Not Misogynous    & $37.49\%\pm1.91\%$   & $46.13\%$         & $36.15\%\pm2.61\%$\\
    \hline
    Not Misogynous    & $37.49\%\pm1.91\%$   & $46.13\%$         & $36.15\%\pm2.61\%$\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{BERTweet binary task}
\label{table:bert_binary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]